# Difference between photon shot noise and electronic shot noise

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What is the difference between photon shot noise and electronic shot noise? Is it possible to prove the difference mathematically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No difference whatsoever.  So long as you have particles arriving at random times, you have shot noise.

Comment: When random number generators are built using the shot noise of photons as a source of entropy that photon shot noise is  known  to have quantum effect. Does electronic shot noise also have quantum effect? If the answer is yes, then how quantum random number generators    are different from random number generators?

Answer (score 1):

Photons are bosons, and exhibit such phenomena as [*bunching* and *antibunching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_antibunching). Electrons are fermions and their shot noise is generally sub-poissonian. See also [Quantum noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_noise).

Answer (score 0):

You are using terms that is often used to describe homodyne detection. Assuming this is the case, then the way we experimentally distinguish between the electronic noise & the quantum noise is that we investigate the output in different situations:

Look at the output of your detection scheme when all of the lasers are turned off (no optical input to your homodyne). This will still give you some small fluctuations, which you can characterize as purely electronic noise.

Next turn your local oscillator on but leave your second field off. If your homodyne is properly balanced, then you should see quantum noise associated with the electric field of the vacuum (which is scaled up in magnitude because of the strength of your local oscillator).

We typically choose a local oscillator strength that is high enough such that the quantum noise is significantly higher than any electronic noise. Typically people who do this work do not work with the quantum mechanics of electrical signals so the electronic noise is never "proven mathematically" to be anything other than something unwanted -- which we experementally try to ignore.